# How to run JUnit tests programmatically in Scala

Tags: scala, junit

I am trying to run JUnit tests inside my Scala application.
Is there any way to do this with JUnit?

In Java, I would programmatically run a JUnit test like this:

```
public org.junit.runner.Result runTest(String test) {
  Class<?> _class = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().loadClass(test);
  org.junit.runner.JUnitCore junit = new org.junit.runner.JUnitCore();
  return junit.run( _class );
}
```

Can I do the same in Scala?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I've no JUnit specific idea, but have you tried a direct translation from Java to Scala?

```
def runTest(test : String) : org.junit.runner.Result = {
  val _class = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader.loadClass(test);
  val junit = new org.junit.runner.JUnitCore();
  junit.run( _class );
}
```

Alternatively, you could write your Java function as a static member of a utility class, and just call it from scala.

```
val result = JUnitUtils.runTest("my.fully.qualified.TestClassName");
```